# we take safety measures, do we also 'take' control measures?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, verbs, collocation

Someone provided me with a PowerPoint presentation and instructed me to convert it into a word document with sentences rather than point form notes. Here is what the PowerPoint slide said:

"Control Measures

-Provide an easy exit

-Wear protective equipment"

The slide talks about what to do when you are working in a tight, enclosed and confied space. Basically, the slide says that when you are working in an enclosed and confined space then 'take' the following control measures: provide an easy exit (that is, make sure it is easy to get out of the enclosed area) and wear protective equipment while working in a confied space.

My question is, does it make sense if I say "When working in a confied and enclosed area, 'take' the following control measures: ensure that there is an easy exit provided to the individual who is working in the confined space, and ensure that the individual working is wearing protective equipment."

Do we 'take' control measures, just as how we take safety measures? If no, what is the correct way of saying what I said in the paragraph above?

Note: I do know that the 'control' measures stated above are really just safety measures, but I'm just wondering if we 'take' control measures like how we take safety measures.

Comment: I would probably use "observe" rather than "take" in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why the expression *take measures* (take action to achieve a particular purpose) cannot take a modifying adjective. *Take (adj) measures* should work with any adjective. (If a word modifies a noun, it is an adjective.) So *Take control measures* is okay.